# Como puedo mostrar el código html que genera mi código jquery en mi web?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Quiero insertar el código html generado a través de JQuery para que el usuario pueda obtener y copiar ese código, pero no logro hacer que se muestre dentro de el id #resultado_codigo . Creo que he llegado a conseguir algo, pero no encuentro como insertar ese resultado en ese div.

```js
 
 $( document ).ready(function() {   

    $("#generar").click(function(){

            var num_filas = $("#filas").val();
            var num_columnas = $("#columnas").val();
 
 $("#resultado_tabla").append("<table id='mi_tabla'>");
        
        for (var i = 0; i < num_filas; i++) 
       
        $("#resultado_tabla table").append("<tr>");

            for (var j = 0; j < num_columnas; j++) 
        
        $("#resultado_tabla tr").append("<td>");
        
        
        console.log($("#mi_tabla").html($("#resultado_codigo")));
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <label>Filas</label><br>
                <input type="number" id="filas" class="numeros"><br>
         
                <label>Columnas</label><br>
                <input type="number" id="columnas" colspan="2" class="numeros">
                <input type="button" value="Generar" id="generar">


<div id="resultado_tabla"></div>

<div id="resultado_codigo"></div>
```

Comment: Hola Azumay404, bienvenido! Te he incluido una refactorización del js porque no me funcionaba. No sé si es necesaria o solamente necesitabas la respuesta para imprimir el resultado. Indícame si prefieres que excluya el js retocado, ok? :-) Yo lo he testeado en un fiddle y me funciona bien. Saludos!

Comment: Muchas gracias! Así esta perfecto, gracias por tu ayuda!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Podrías usar la función text():

```
$("#resultado_codigo").text(resultado); //resultado contendría el html previamente generado.
```

Por ejemplo:

```
var resultado = $("#resultado_tabla").html();
$("#resultado_codigo").text(resultado);
```

Si también quieres mostrarlo en consola:

```
 var resultado = $("#resultado_tabla").html();
 $("#resultado_codigo").text(resultado);
 console.log(resultado);
```

Por otro lado, creo que tu código no genera la tabla correctamente.
Lo he refactorizado así:

De este modo puedes imprimir en cualquier momento el html que generas por consola o el medio que prefieras, y se ejecuta sin errores generando la tabla:

Tu javascript refactorizado:

```
function generar(){

    var num_filas = $("#filas").val();
    var num_columnas = $("#columnas").val();
    var markup ="<table>";     

    for (var i = 0; i < num_filas; i++) {
      markup += "<tr>";

        for (var j= 0; j < num_columnas; j++) {
          markup += "<td>"+(j+1)+"</td>";
          //he añadido aquí el cierre de cada columna
        }

      markup += "</tr>";
      //aquí he añadido el cierre de las filas
    }

    markup += "</table>";  //cierre de la tabla
    $("#resultado_tabla").append(markup);
    var resultado = $("#resultado_tabla").html();
    $("#resultado_codigo").text(resultado);
    console.log(resultado);

 };
```

Pequeño cambio en el html del botón para llamar la función:

```
<input type="button" value="Generar" id="generar" onclick="generar();">
```